What's the piece of furniture in modern living rooms that looks like a lower portion of a living-room cabinet called?
I'm looking for the name of this particular piece of furniture that looks like the lower portion of a living-room cabinet.

It's usually under a TV, or is where the TV is placed. In this photo there are two speakers on top of it. I've never owned one, but I guess you put disks and media players and magazines in it. It mainly has only drawers and no doors.
So far, the options I've found seem dubious.

Cabinets/cupboards: the pictures I've found for these seem to indicate that they have to be larger and have a top part with doors, oftentimes glass doors for displaying china plates. Now I did find the above picture by Googling "living room cabinet", but I'm not quite sure if this really counts, and I'm not willing to trust random listicles.
Madias: there's not a whole lot in this linked Wikipedia article. Not sure if this word accurately names the modern piece, or some "High Renaissance" one.
Sideboards/Buffets: the shape of these are different, and they seem to be used (at least "traditionally") in the kitchen or the dining room for storing dishes.
Chests of drawers/dressers/bureaux: the shape is still different, and these are in the bedroom for storing clothes.
Credenzas: this word probably the most likely candidate given the first picture in the linked Wikipedia article, although I don't know where the picture was taken.

Here's a perfunctory "sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used":

Look for it in the pile of Halo disks in the _______. I don't remember which drawer, though.

Update: While Kate Bunting's suggestion, TV unit, seems to be a good starting point, I want to officially accept terdon's answer because it's slightly more comprehensive. I, too, looked up TV unit and hit this IKEA webpage, which has a category of products called TV unit, TV bench and TV cabinet (though you have to look at the webpage's name). But still, thanks to both of you and the rest of the answerers.

credenza has had a lot of currency in the US.  Most furniture stores
would know what was meant.  As you can see from this link, the terms credenza, sideboard, buffet, etc are imprecise and used interchangeably: https://www.macys.com/shop/featured/credenza?ss=true

@TimR The link you gave is probably dynamic and not usable.

Just search for "credenza" at macys com and it brings back anything like a credenza, TV stands, sideboards, buffets, servers, you name it.

credenza don't usually have TV's on them.

I have often seen this called a "TV unit". For example, this is what Made call it: https://www.made.com/shop/living-room-furniture/tv-units

You will also find it called a "TV bench", e.g. by IKEA:


TV unit was first suggested by Kate Bunting.

TV cabinet is also a term I've seen. Though that may be more for larger cabinets that enclose the entire TV set (and if very fancy even behind doors).

All the items of furniture you list long pre-date the invention of television. The items you are asking about were introduced when people started using video cassette recorders in combination with their TV sets, and needed a shelf to store the VCR and cassettes.
Googling TV stand finds a good number of examples, also TV unit and Media unit.

I like TV unit. To me, a TV stand is the thing with legs that keeps the TV upright on the unit.

I bought one from John Lewis some years ago when we first got a flat-screen TV, they called it a 'television stand'. I see they still use that term. That's not the one we bought, by the way. I agree with @Greybeard - the 'stand' can be the little legs or single foot under the screen part or an item of furniture which may or may not look like a long cabinet. Our telly has two stands, then.

@Greybeard I've been calling the item of furniture a TV stand since before TVs started to need something to keep them upright on it.

Not a particular piece of furniture though, is it?

low (media) console

low meaning typically 20" high or less (per Home Depot), which is well below standard table height (30"H) to accommodate large screen TV heights (and so, widths are generally ~70"W and up, as required)

media may be omitted (in proper context) because one definition of console is a media cabinet (per OL&G), but there are also "console bookcases" (low and wide) and "console tables" (not so low, like a "sofa table")

console meaning a media cabinet "designed to rest directly on the floor" (M-W) for stability and optimal viewing angle.



Definition of console
as in cabinet
a storage case typically having doors and shelves

a custom-built walnut console holds all of their home-theater components

[Merriam-Webster]


To be very specific (about "this particular piece of furniture"), one might say: 'I'm looking for a 4-drawer, low (media) console with open shelves in the center, between 78" and 80" long.' However, a console may have doors, drawers, open shelves, or any combination of those.

But if searching online, just "low console" returns many results; and it should be readily understood by salespeople, interior designers, and people who own them (or who watch home design shows regularly, in my case). Of course, if the owner has just the one, and provides contextual clues, just "the console" should suffice.


Sources: Oxford Languages/Google, Merriam-Webster, The Home Depot, Rooms To Go, and various other retailers and designers.
Image of a credenza, for comparison, in a hotel elevator corridor, featuring goldstone handles and hairpin legs.


see also "lowboy", traditionally a "dressing table" but has broadened in scope over the last century+

@Yorik- Nice word. It could also be a 'home-theater console' and be low by necessity. I can't really tell how big that screen is, but it's not a mega screen, for sure.

In Japanese they use the term "low board" as a loanword or Japanese-English term, and Google returns mostly Japanese sites for that term. The implication is it's not just for the TV and recorder but has space for other stuff.

As well as TV stand, it can also be a TV plinth.

Penny Wood
Build our Bed
Denelli Italia
Hatfields

A plinth in architecture is “a rectangular block of stone on which a statue or pillar stands” [Collins] and the term has been broadened to any such supporting structure.
[Other examples are available; the four listed were fairly high up in search results.]

plinth is very BrE. We don't say that in the states. But it's a great word and bravo to the Brits for using it.

That's an intriguing use of plinth. To me, the word brings to mind something that is taller than it is wide, so it's surprising to see it applied to something that is clearly wider than it is tall. I wonder how it came about.

In the US, a plinth is usually a block of trim in the corner of a room that the base molding or crown molding butts into.  https://www.wayfair.com/home-improvement/pdp/ekena-millwork-6-14w-x-9-34h-x-1p-diane-plinth-block-ekml1402.html

I wouldn't expect one to have drawers or doors or anything, not even fluted edges; seems more minimalist than just modern. But I like it. Nice word.

It may be called an entertainment center, although this somewhat implies that it houses multiple electronic devices or physical media, rather than just a TV. It would be common for an entertainment center to be a larger piece of furniture with additional shelves or cabinets to the sides or above the TV, but it could also refer to just a low piece of furniture as shown. An entertainment center will almost always hold a TV, and may also hold other entertainment media items like speakers, game consoles, a DVD player, or DVDs themselves.
I will note that the term has seen a marked drop-off in usage since the early 2000s, coinciding with the popularization of streaming wireless TV services, wall-mountable flatscreen TVs, and less emphasis on physical media. Nowadays it's perfectly possible for a TV setup to consist of solely a screen on a wall, in contrast to the past when you'd need a dedicated piece of furniture to hold multiple bulky entertainment devices.

This is what we called it in two different furniture shops where I worked in N.E. USA (S. Central PA).

Same for the Midwest USA.
